# Recently updated db records not reflected in follow-on SELECT

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a spring mvc app with an h2 database. Db objects are updated using the JPA criteria and spring @Transaction annotation. See findBySymbol() and update() at bottom.

After update() is done, the app calls findBySymbol() to run some logic on the updated records. The findBySymbol() SQL is correct. The problem is that results from findBySymbol() have *not* been updated. This is puzzling because Hibernate trace logs show the update binded parameters, the SQL update statement, and the int result of executeUpdate(). Also confusing is that I can query the db at that point directly and see that the records are, in fact, updated.

What do I need to do to be able to have the app query the db immediately after the update and return updated data?

```
import com.example.mycompany.beans.AEarnings;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import javax.persistence.criteria.ParameterExpression;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Path;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaUpdate;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
public class AnnualEarningsDaoImpl implements AnnualEarningsDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;        

    @Override
    public List<AEarnings> findBySymbol(String s) {

        // CriteriaBuilder 
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

        // CriteriaQuery
        CriteriaQuery<AEarnings> cQuery = cb.createQuery(AEarnings.class);

        // Root
        Root<AEarnings> ae = cQuery.from(AEarnings.class);

        // Parameters
        ParameterExpression<String> p = cb.parameter(String.class);

        // Db command
        cQuery.select(ae).where(cb.equal(ae.get("symbol"), p));

        // TypedQuery
        TypedQuery<AEarnings> query = entityManager.createQuery(cQuery);

        // Set Parameter
        query.setParameter(p, s);

        // Results
        List<AEarnings> results = query.getResultList();
        
        // Return
        return results;
    }
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(
            String a, LocalDate b, String c,
            BigDecimal d, BigDecimal e, BigDecimal f) {
        
        // CriteriaBuilder
        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

        // CriteriaUpdate<AEarnings>
        CriteriaUpdate<AEarnings> update
                = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(AEarnings.class);
        // Root
        Root<AEarnings> root = update.from(AEarnings.class);

        // Holds parameters
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        // Predicates
        predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("a"), a));
        predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("b"), b));
        predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("c"), c));
        
        // Update
        update
            .set(root.get("d"), d)
            .set(root.get("e"), e)
            .set(root.get("f"), f)
            .where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));

        // Execute
        int i = entityManager.createQuery(update).executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Updated: " + i);
    }

}
```

Updated with AEarningsServiceImpl, which in this case only calls dao methods:

```
import com.example.mycompany.beans.AEarnings;
import com.example.mycompany.dao.AEarningsDao;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class AEarningsServiceImpl implements AEarningsService{

    @Autowired
    AEarningsDao aEarningsDao;

    @Override
    public List<AnnualEarnings> findBySymbol(String sym) {
        return annualEarningsDao.findBySymbol(sym);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(
            String symbol, LocalDate fiscalEndDate, String fiscalPeriod, 
            BigDecimal prev, BigDecimal diff, BigDecimal diffPercent) {
        annualEarningsDao.update(symbol, fiscalEndDate, fiscalPeriod,
                prev, diff, diffPercent);
    }

    // save()...    
    // delete()...
}
```

Updated with pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
            https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>appmaker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>Spring Boot Stock App</description>
    <name>app</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Updated with code that calls AEarningsService:

```
package com.example.mycompany.beans.helpers;

import com.example.mycompany.beans.AnnualEarnings;
import com.example.mycompany.beans.Token;
import com.example.mycompany.beans.Url;
import com.example.mycompany.service.AnnualEarningsService;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class AnnualHelper {

    private static final BigDecimal HUNDRED = new BigDecimal(100);
    private static final String EARNINGS_4_TAG = "/earnings/4?period=annual&token=";
    private static final String EARNINGS_1_TAG = "/earnings/1?period=annual&token=";
    private Url url;

    @Autowired
    private AnnualEarningsService annualEarningsService;
    
    // Call class methods, filter for earnings of size > 0 for initial run
    public List<AnnualEarnings> run(String domain, String token, BigDecimal percent) {

        // Holds results
        List<AnnualEarnings> results = new ArrayList<>();

        // Grab symbols
        ...

        // Loop through incoming symbols
        symbols.forEach((symbol) -> {

            // Grab most recent fiscalPeriod for symbol
            List<AnnualEarnings> exists = annualEarningsService.findBySymbol(symbol);

            // Check if symbol is in db
            // If exists, log
            if (!exists.isEmpty()) {
                log(...);

            // Else, process new symbol
            } else {
            
                try {
                    List<AnnualEarnings> earnings = processEarnings(symbol, percent);

                    // Filter for List<AnnualEarnings> greater than zero, add to results
                    if (!earnings.isEmpty()) {

                        // Add to results
                        earnings.forEach(e -> results.add(e));
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    logInfo("runAEInitial() - Exception: ", ex);
                }
            }
        });

        return results;
    }

    // For one symbol, parse, save, update initial earnings
    private List<AnnualEarnings> processEarnings(String symbol, BigDecimal percent) {

        // Create Url
        ...

        // Grab api response
        String response = "";
        try {
            response = CommonUtils.callApi(url);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log(...);
        }

        // Catch empty json object returned from API
        if (response.length() == 2) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        // Parse json from api, save to db
        parseAndSaveEarnings(response);

        // Update AnnualEarnings Objects
        updateEarnings(symbol);

        // From db, grab symbol's eearnings for last 4 quarters
        List<AnnualEarnings> updatedEarnings = annualEarningsService.findBySymbol(symbol);

        return filterByDiffPercent(updatedEarnings, percent);
    }
    
    
    // Update previous, diff values of AnnualEarnings objects just created
    private void updateEarnings(String symbol) {

        // Grab all objects from db for symbol
        List<AnnualEarnings> inList = 
                annualEarningsService.findBySymbol(symbol);

        // Update prev & diff values of incoming AnnualEarnings object
        for (int i = 1; i < inList.size(); i++) {

            // Existing object fiscalEndDate
            LocalDate fiscalEndDate = inList.get(i - 1).getFiscalEndDate();

            // Existing object fiscalPeriod
            String fiscalPeriod = inList.get(i - 1).getFiscalPeriod();

            // Get original
            BigDecimal current = inList.get(i - 1).getActualEPS();

            // Get previous
            BigDecimal prev = inList.get(i).getActualEPS();

            // Get diff 
            BigDecimal diff = current.subtract(prev);

            // Get diffPercent
            BigDecimal diffPercent = (diff.divide(prev, 4, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)).movePointRight(2);
            
            // Align num signs
            diffPercent = CommonUtils.alignSigns(diff, diffPercent);

            // Update
            annualEarningsService.update(symbol, fiscalEndDate, fiscalPeriod, prev, diff, diffPercent);
        }
    }

    // Parse json string returned from API, save to db
    private void parseAndSaveEarnings(String str) {

        // Create parser
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject fullObj;

        try {
            // Full json object
            fullObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(str);

            // First layer
            JSONArray earningsArray = (JSONArray) fullObj.get("earnings");

            // Symbol
            String jsonSymbol = fullObj.get("symbol").toString();

            // Loop through earnings for one symbol
            earningsArray.forEach((earningsJson) -> {

                logInfo("", "");

                // Create jsonobject
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) earningsJson;

                // Grab values
                String jsonFiscEndDateStr = jsonObject.get("fiscalEndDate").toString();
                
                LocalDate jsonFiscEndDate = CommonUtils.convertStringToLocalDateAnnualEarnings(jsonFiscEndDateStr);
                
                String jsonFiscPer = jsonObject.get("fiscalPeriod").toString();

                // Create update object
                AnnualEarnings e = new AnnualEarnings();

                // Grab data, set properties
                String actEps = jsonObject.get("actualEPS").toString();

                e.setFiscalEndDate(jsonFiscEndDate);
                e.setSymbol(jsonSymbol);
                e.setActualEPS(new BigDecimal(actEps));
                e.setFiscalPeriod(jsonFiscPer);

                // Save 
                annualEarningsService.save(e);
           });
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            logSevere("parseAndSaveAEarningsInitial()", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    // Filter objects with earnings difference > 25%
    private List<AnnualEarnings> filterByDiffPercent(List<AnnualEarnings> updatedEarnings, BigDecimal percent) {

        // Hold results
        List<AnnualEarnings> results = new ArrayList<>();

        
        // Loop through objects, filter out objects with diffPercent > 25
        updatedEarnings.forEach((earn) -> {
            
            // THIS IS WHERE I FIND THAT ENTITY OBJECTS RETURNED HAVE NOT BEEN
            //  UPDATED
            logInfo("filterByDiffPercent() - earn: ", earn.toString());

            BigDecimal diffPercent = earn.getDiffPercent();

            if (diffPercent != null && diffPercent.compareTo(percent) == 1) {
                results.add(earn);
            }
        });
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: EarningsServiceImpl class Autowires earningsDao and calls its methods. update() in EarningsServiceImpl has @Transactional, but the class does not.

Comment: Show the class (or the relevant parts of it) that calls those methods. You're also missing a `@Transactional ` attribute from your `findBySymbol` method, which you'll want to add.

Comment: I removed Transactional from AEarningsServiceImpl, added the propogation, but I got same result.

Comment: Dont do two things at the same time. Just remove Transactional from AEarningsServiceImpl. I would suggest not to use Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW because: https://codete.com/blog/spring-transaction-propagation-modes/

Comment: And your code is really big and difficult for me to understand, man. eg. The AnnualHelper is calling findBySymbol method so many times. It can be refactored a lot and made a lot cleaner (according to me). If possible, you can put all the code in a public Repository (github/bitbucket) and share it , so that it becomes easy for me to set up in local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use annotation `@Transactional` you need to configure your Spring with `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation or XML analog: `<tx:annotation-driven/>`.
And properly init TransactionManager bean.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html

Because of Spring `@Transactional` annotation works through Aspects.

Comment: @EnableTransactionManagement is optional in Spring boot, provided that spring-data* or spring-tx are found in classpath

Comment: Since I am not using spring-data-*, I added @EnableTransactionManagement to my data configuration class. I'll work on the TransactionManager bean

Answer (score 0):

*Update:*

Instead of having @Transactional both at service and repo methods, please keep only at one place.

**Remove the @Transactional from service method. Keep @Transactional at both findBySymbol and update methods of repo impl.**

---

*Initial Observation before the service class was shown:*

This is because Hibernate **uses cache in same session**. (L1 cache by default)

In order to **force a L1 cache refresh** you can **use the refresh(Object) method of Session**.

From the Hibernate Docs,

```
Re-read the state of the given instance from the underlying database. It is inadvisable to use this to implement long-running sessions that span many business tasks. This method is, however, useful in certain special circumstances. For example

 - where a database trigger alters the object state upon insert or update
 - after executing direct SQL (eg. a mass update) in the same session
 - after inserting a Blob or Clob
```

Comment: He is most likely using the same session

Comment: It may be the source of the problem if the transaction boundaries aren't correctly set, but just using `refresh()` isn't the solution, as this is a design issue and you'd need to see the full code and all the transaction boundaries to design the proper code flow.

Comment: @Kayaman agreed. The asker needs to share the full code

Comment: Update with AEarningsServiceImpl.

Comment: @chocalaca also please show the class/method from where you are calling the update method first , followed by findBySymbol

Comment: Updated with pom & code that calls update() and findBySymbol(). Please see comment in filterByDiffPercent().